# canon LBP6030/6040/6018L

Tags: printing, canon

how to install the canon LBP6030/6040/6018L on the tosthiba satelit laptop?
i'm using the ubuntu 14LTS and i can't find a driver for it. 
sorry i'm reading the forums for almost 4 h but i cant find the problem.
it let's me to recognize the printer as mentioned above only with generic driver.

recognizes as canon LBP6030/6040/6018L
location usb://Canon/LBP6030/6040/6018L?serial=0000A1F3K9K3
make model: Generic text-only printer
printer status : Idle or Idle - File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocapt3

Comment: make model :Canon LBP6000/LBP6018 CAPT (UK)   message code for error Canon LBP6000/LBP6018 CAPT (UK)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download **Linux** driver from official site.
2. Execute file located in gzip directory **Debian**

Comment: Hello. This may be an answer but what is the official site. It would have been nice if you had said what the site was.